# Connect to secondary database on Firestore

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a secondary database on Firestore and a new serviceAccount.json key, and connected as always:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore

# Use a service account
cred = credentials.Certificate('path/to/serviceAccount_2.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore.client()
```

When trying to query this new database, using this new key, queries get routed to the primary database.

Is there a way to achieve this? I have found documentation for [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/) here, but not for firestore.

How would you resolve this?